# how to get e-mails on gmail account using PHPmailer

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm really new to this field. I am working on my portfolio. I have made modal contact form (bootstrap) for **"contact me"**. I'm not getting mails on my gmail account from php . I'm using PHP mailer and following is the code of my php with file name **contact-form.php**:

```
<?php

// check for form submission - if it doesn't exist then send back to contact form**
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$message=
    'Name:  '.$_POST['name'].'<br />
    Email:  '.$_POST['email'].'<br />
    Message:    '.$_POST['contact-message'];
require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

// Instantiate Class
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set up SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();    // Set up SMTP connection
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // Connection with SMTP does require authorization
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";      // Connect using a TLS connection
$mail->Host ="smtp.gmail.com"; //Gmail SMTP address
$mail->Port = 465; // Gmail SMTP port No idea what this is suppose to be
$mail->Encoding ='7bit';

$mail->Username = "mygmailid@gmail.com";  // Gmail address
$mail->Password ="Password";  // Gmail Password

// Compose
$mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'],$_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = "Mail from Portfolio";
$mail->MsgHTML($message);

//Send To
$mail->AddAddress("recipientmail@gmail.com", "Recipient Name");
$result = $mail->Send();
$message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed';
unset($mail);

}
```

I have linked all my html pages with **contact-form.php** as:

```
<form action="contactform.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

When I clicked on the send message button it's directing me to the contact-form.php but nothing is happening.

Please Please help me out I have been stuck in this issue since last week.

Any suggestion or help will be highly appreciable.

Thank you in advance :)
Tayyaba.

Comment: Can you make some debug output to verify is the data is transmitted to this form?

Comment: As I said I'm new to this field can you please elaborate your question? Thank you

Comment: I've seen the following video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUUMEUETCxw)

Comment: For instance, add some `echo "something"` inside your `if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {` condition so you know whether the code is executed. Then check the content of your `$message` variable for success or failure

Answer (score 0):

i appreciate your code you have applied so far, as it is hard to debug your code, it would be better if you test your code with static info, 
i have given a working example below:

```
    $email = new PHPMailer();
    $email->From      = 'amrinder.salentro@gmail.com';
    $email->FromName  = 'Amrinder Singh';
    $email->Subject   = 'Hello';
    $email->Body      = "How are you karan";
    $email->AddAddress( 'amrinder.salentro@gmail.com' );
    $email->AddAttachment( 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE' , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );   //optional 
    return $email->Send();
```

i hope it would help you. please go with it...
thanks... :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've applied it but it's not working for me. May be I'm missing something. Should I have to add POP server in my gmail account settings?  @Insomnia

Comment: @Synchro the question says "to gmail account" not "through gmail account". read it again..

Comment: The OP's code is sending both through and to a gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you start again using [a known-good example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps) for sending through gmail, and make sure you're using latest PHPMailer. As for your script, this line means that your mail handling code will only ever be run when the form is *not* submitted, and since this will result in sending errors, which you are not showing, you won't see anything happen!

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

This should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: Thank you @Synchro I'll work on your suggestion and let you know about that.

Comment: I've tried GitHUb solution that you gave. Fortunately it is working but it's giving me the following error:
**Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.**

what does this suppose to mean???

Comment: You need to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).